# Evaluate $\sin (\cot ^{-1} (1+x)) = \cos (\tan^{-1} (x))$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

Let $cot^{-1} (1+x)=a$

Then $x =1-\cot a$

So $$\sin a =\cos (\tan^{1}(1-\cot a))$$

$$a=\frac{\pi}{2}- \tan^{-1} (1-\cot a)$$
$$\cot a =\frac 12$$

So $x=\frac 12$, but given answer is $-\frac 12$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How have you defined arccot? There is some ambiguity: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseCotangent.html

Comment: The first line: $\cot^{-1} (1+x)=a \implies x=-1+\cot(a)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sin (\cot ^{-1} (1+x)) = \cos (\tan^{-1} (x)).$
Let $\cot^{-1} (1+x)=A \implies \cot A =1+x.$ So $LHS=\sin A= 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2+2x+x^2}}$ Let $\tan B=x \implies RHS=\cos B =\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$. Finally $LHS=RHS \implies 2+2x+x^2=1+x^2 \implies x=-1/2.$

Comment: How did you write the value of $\sin A$?

Comment: Make a right angle triangle wit on angle as $A$ using $1+x=\cot A$, then from this triangle find $Sin A$

Answer (score 1):

$\sin(\cot^{-1}(1+x))=\cos\left(\dfrac\pi2-\cot^{-1}(1+x)\right)=\cos(\tan^{-1}(1+x))$

We need $$\tan^{-1}(1+x)=2n\pi\pm\tan^{-1}x$$  where $n$ is any integer

Considering the '-' sign,   $$\tan^{-1}(1+x)+\tan^{-1}x=2n\pi$$

Using [Principal values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values), $$-\pi<\tan^{-1}(1+x)+\tan^{-1}x<\pi\implies n=0$$

Consequently, $$\tan^{-1}(1+x)=-\tan^{-1}x=\tan^{-1}(-x)$$

$$\iff1+x=-x\iff x=?$$

Check for the '+' sign

Comment: @Aditya,  What if $$x\to\infty?$$ or $$x\to-\infty?$$